# How to get list of column names of a sqlite db file

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Sorry for the rookie question. I have a sqlite file and I need to get table column names. How can I get them?

Comment: If you are using FIrefox (or don't mind using installing ti just for this purpose): https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `pragma table_info(spamtable)` command.  The table names will be index 1 of the returned tuples.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master
WHERE tbl_name = 'table_name' AND type = 'table'
```

Then parse this value with Reg Exp.

You can also use:

```
PRAGMA table_info(table_name)
```